# Send values from HTML <li> in form

Tags: html, css, select, html-lists

as far as I know there seems to be very limited options to style a `<option>` tag inside a `<select>` dropdown and honestly it looks rather boring, so I thought I could create a dropdown with some `<ul>` `<li>` tags, but I'm not sure its possible?

I read that some says you can hide inputs in the `<li>` tag and get values that way.

Is there a good way to solve this problem? It's just a simple dropdown with 3 static values to send 1, 2 or 3!

Answer (score 0):

This is called a pure CSS dropdown menu.
You can find a really good example here:

https://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/